# SQL Server import export wizard

Tags: sql-server, import, export, wizard

I have a 64 bit OS and 32 bit MS Office suite. The SQL Server 2014 64 bit import export wizard will not let me import/export to Excel; not an option. I need a 32 bit import/export wizard. I tried everything so far. Can you help?

Comment: What import/export wizard are you using exactly? The one that comes with SSMS is 32bit (as SSMS itself is also 32bit).

Comment: this tool is really useful, can I install that without install whole SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

I have both:

[image: In the Apps menu below Import and Export Data 64-bit is SQL Server 2017 Import and Export Data 64 bit and SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data 64 bit.]

look in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn
```

for DTSWizard.exe

Comment: Oh thank you so very much.  You made my day.  I spent hours on that and never thought to look there.  I pinned it to my taskbar, the little devil.

Comment: I found the file, but when I run it nothing happens