# How to force SQL Server Management Studio to use 64 bit Import Wizard to avoid error: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered

Tags: installation, import, ssms, xlsx, ms-jet-ace

I have 64 bit O/S and 64 bit Office installed.
I have installed the MS Data Access components (tried various versions 64 bit/32 bit).

I cannot get SSMS to import Excel files.  I get error Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered.

Instead I have to run the 64 bit DTSWizard.exe manually.

Is there a way to force SSMS to use the 64 bit Import Wizard?

No big deal... But it really amazes me that MS does this!!!
(Crazy - why do they do it?).

This post helped a lot:
[SQL Server import export wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860479/sql-server-import-export-wizard)