# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I am trying to import data via Excel but import isn't running. I read all the other forum answers before asking here.
I have 64 bit versions of both (Excel and SQL Server).
I have reinstalled Access DB Client.

Moreover I ran query `master.dbo.xp_enum_oledb_providers` and the provider is available. I don't know what else to do.

If anyone can help with this issue, I'd be grateful.
How do I register/ re-register it ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? How do you run the import?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I go to my database --.right click--> import data-->import from Excel. It used to work earlier.

Comment: What version of SQL Server and Excel are you using? Where is the driver installed on the server or on the client? What version of SSMS are you using? Keep in mind that SSMS is 32 bit application.

Comment: @Alex MS Excel 2016 16.0 64 Bit and MS SQL Server 2019 15.0 64 bit. SSMS is showing X64 which means 64 bit, right ?

Comment: Where does SSMS show x64? There is no mention of 64bit SSMS version on the internet.

Comment: This may be of help to you (especially the linked question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328587/how-to-force-sql-server-management-studio-to-use-64-bit-import-wizard-to-avoid-e

Answer (score 0):

You have SQL Studio Management (32-bit) but need to install the 32-bit verison.

- Microsoft Access Database Engine V12 https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255 (For your question)
- Microsoft Access Database Engine V16 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 (For future question when you observe a Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 error)

If you already installed the 64-bit version you will be prevented to install the 32-bit version.

A workaround is to open `CMD.exe` and run: `"accessdatabaseengine (1).exe" /quiet`. The `/quiet` overrides the above constraint.